# Site Optimisation: What do you think I should do?

Tags: structure, low-search

So I have an SEO and website designing startup [Pluton Ltd.](https://pluton.ltd)https://pluton.ltd
Now I have tried to make it look awesome but it is taking a lot of time to load.
I have even compressed and optimized my images.
What else can be done?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify in your question what version of ExpressoinEngine you are using, and something about the hosting platform used (e.g. Apache or Nginx etc.) including which version of php is being used. This will help other users determine good answers to your questions.

Comment: Closing since this seems to be a Wordpress site. If that's a mistake, and this is an EE site, please revise your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

A great place to start with things like this is to checkout [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpluton.ltd%2F). It looks like a couple things:

1. Serve your images in next gen formats (webp)
2. Fix your render blocking resources, like styles that need are being loaded in the header
3. Fix your server time. It's taking way too long.

You asked this in the EE Stack, but your site looks to be WordPress. There are a load of WP plugins that can help with this kind of thing, like WP Rocket or Hummingbird, that can take care of a number of these things.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is.... Looking into your page code...  is this a WordPress site?   it looks to have a ton of elements from there...

Looked some more...  I think you might have posted to the wrong forum.  I can't help much with WP.

UPDATE: One recommendation I can make is to run your site through something like seositecheckup.com.  It will at least tell you where to start. it looks like... although you pass, the items you fail are all directly related to site speed. You are extremely heavy on the image side.

R

Answer (score 0):

It's a Wordpress site so this is indeed the wrong forum.

Your total home page weight is 15mb so no wonder its slow, here's what's causing that.

CSS 2.45mb
JS 2.99mb
FONTS 0.45mb
IMAGES 9.09mb

In an ideal world a home page like yours should come in at less than 1mb.

Answer (score 0):

Use WGET and render this as a static site or use a static site Wordpress plugin.